# How to troubleshoot when the JVM young gc cost time rapidly increase

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

### Problem Description

There are an application cluster with 16 instances. Two instances of them cost more than 1000ms while performing young gc which is very unusual.

Through the monitor dashboard we can see the young gc cost time is still increasing.

- gc duration pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMejX.png
- the gc-log analyze report of one of the two instances: [gc-log analyze report ]
  (https://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=YXJjaGl2ZWQvMjAyMS8wNi8yLy0tYXBpLTliOGE4NzgzLWQzOTctNGVjYy04NTEzLTdlMDI5Njc3NzMwMzQ3ZDYxODllLWI4NDAtNGVjYS05MTIxLTkyYzVmZDZjNWFmMi50eHQ=&channel=API)

### Some Config Info

#### JVM

```
-Xms4g -Xmx4g -Xmn2g -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=5000 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/data/logs/app-gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/data/logs/app.dump -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
```

#### docker container

- 8GB of memory and 4 CPUs

### My Question

The other 14 instances has the same interval of young gc time-cost as the two problematic instances. But the former ones only takes less than 20ms.

This is my first time to encounter this kind of problem, Please give me some suggestions for troubleshooting based on ur experience.

Thx in advance~

Answer (score 0):

(started out as a comment but got too long).
1, What JDK version are you running? If it's late Java 8 and beyond, leave CMS.

2, You are using quite a few flags. If you can replicate the behaviour, remove all flags except logging and max heap size and see what happens. Some of the flags are default on already, you can check with `XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags`.
The meta space allocation for instance isn't needed according to the report.

3, Generally speaking, gc performance is best when the live set is small and looking at the graph, it's far from. Tracing to old gen is generally expensive so that might be one reason for the long gc times. 
Looking at the GC duration graph, notice that the behaviour goes bad when the heap usage before gc goes to 2.5 GB. Before that it's running as it should. But that increase of 500 MB is enough to kick vm into some other state. You could try to check if you can see anything weird happening at that time (around 10.30ish am, 1st June).

(as an aside, it's funny that the y axis is labeled as millibit. Thats a unit I've never seen before).